# Fundamentals of web-applications vs http server

Tags: http, web-applications, webserver

I am required to preface this question with a **disclaimer**:
Im sorry if the question is silly and I am sure this information is on the Internet *somewhere*, but the reason why I ask here is because, I lack the knowledge to begin my research anywhere useful I don't need to read what an http server is, but rather what it's place in a backend environment is. Somehow, I was not able to find anything useful, which is why I believe that the idea I have of this issue at this moment is completely wrong.

I am fairly new to the ins and outs of how the web works. I believe I have good knowledge on how the http protocol works, frontend development and programming. But I don't seem to be able to connect the pieces.

What happens after the request reaches the http server?

Specifically, I can't seem to understand what exactly the back-end means. For example, if someone were to use Django as their backend framework -> what would be the role the application written in python(django) plays? Does it interpret the server request and if so, what are applications such as apache http server used for in a situation such as this?
I don't understand the link between the http server and the web application.
How would you get a web application to run on a server?

I understand that if you just need a web server to serve static html files than apache server would be enough. But how does it work when user data has to be inserted into the html file, or when the database has to be updated as a result of a http request.
I believe this would be the responsibility of the web application, but how do they interact?

**tl;dr:**

- What is the role of an http-server vs role of a web application?
- How do they interact?
- To point is an http server software such as apache or nginx necessary?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the role of an http-server vs role of a web application?

An HTTP-Server is roughly an application that serves files to clients. Basically those files are of HTML type, thus contains hyperlinks that refers to other files.

A web application is just a set of related HTML files, that the user navigates through.

That is the base; as that model can be extended : files can be generated dynamically, of type different than HTML, etc.

> How do they interact?

The server manages the files and send them to the client application (usually a web browser).

> To point is an http server software such as apache or nginx necessary?

Sure it is, as it is the core infrastructure of a web application. Your web application is a set of HTML files that are accessed through a web-browser that ask the HTTP-server to obtain them.